# Tensorflow: filter by some condition label of a batch in the loss operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two label batches in my network. The first batch is noisy label, the second is the validated one. Not all the noisy label have a validated label, but the batches have the same size. The loss must be calculated only on the validated label. Is there a way to filter a batch in order to use only the validated label in the loss?

This is my loss definition:

```
def loss_clean_v1(label_output, label_verified):
    loss_clean_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(label_output, label_verified)))
    # debug
    loss_clean_value = tf.Print(loss_clean_value, [loss_clean_value], message="Loss label cleaning: ")
    return loss_clean_value
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to filter a batch in order to use only the validated label in the loss?

Comment: When the noisy label doesn't have a corresponding validated label, what it is assigned then?. Can you give an example of both labels, and how you want to calculate the loss on those examples?.

Comment: i will use a fake label. This is an example of verified label: `img_label_test_verified = np.zeros((1, 6012))`,`a = np.array([1, 0, 50, 60, 1000, 5012, 14, 16, 17, 18, 34])`,`img_label_test_verified[0, a] = 1`. the noisy label is similar but with confidence value instead of 1. The fake label probably will be a vector with all -1. I want to use only the label verified and its corresponding output_label in the loss operation.

Comment: This is the behavior i want: `res = tf.where([False, True], verified_label, label_cleaned)`, `loss_clean_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(label_cleaned, res)))`. My problem is how to get the boolean vector [False, True] in tensorflow. i have tried with `condition = tf.not_equal(verified_label, np.full((2, 6012), -1))`, but tf.not_equal is element-wise, so i get a boolean vector of shape (2,6012). Is there a way to use a condition to get vector like [False, True]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem!

`label` is the batch of output label obtained from a cleaning to a batch of noisy label. `label_verified` is a batch of verified label; not every noisy label has a verified one, so i use a fake label of all -1 `np.full((1, 6012), -1)`.

In my loss must be used only the verified label. i need to filter the `label_verified` batch.

To do this i use `tf.where()` with a boolean vector, with size the number of label in the batch, as condition, like `[False, True]`.

The problem is that Tensorflow provides only element-wise comparison operators that not produce the boolean vector i need.

To get that vector i refined the element-wise condition result: `condition_refined = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(condition, tf.int32), 1), tf.bool)`

The batch result of the filtering is `label_filtered = tf.where(condition_refined, label_verified, label)`.

I use a label output if the condition is `False` because my loss has a subtraction the verified and the output label. So *output label - output label* contribute 0 to the loss.

Here is my code:

```
def loss_clean(label, label_verified):

    # in np.full, 2 is my batch size 
    condition = tf.not_equal(label_verified, np.full((2, 6012), -1))

    # debug
    condition = tf.Print(condition, [condition], message="Condition: ")

    condition_refined = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(condition, tf.int32), 1), tf.bool)

    # debug
    condition_refined = tf.Print(condition_refined, [condition_refined], message="Condition_refined: ")

    label_filtered = tf.where(condition_refined, label_verified, label)

    # debug
    label_filtered = tf.Print(label_filtered, [label_filtered], message="Label_filtered: ")

    loss_clean_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(label, label_filtered)))

    # debug
    loss_clean_value = tf.Print(loss_clean_value, [loss_clean_value], message="Loss label cleaning: ")

    return loss_clean_value
```